# On my performance review, I got a 2.76 out of 4. How should I interpret this?

Tags: performance-reviews

The other week I got a review from work and it came out to 2.76 / 4.

I got kinda upset about it; because 2.76/4 = 69%

If I got that in school, it'd be like a high D.

But I've talked to some people and they told me it's not so bad.

I don't know if I should believe them or not, so I thought I'd as more people.

P.S. I've only worked at my job for like 3 years and it's pretty extensive out there, there's a lot of stuff to know and learn and at one point the Pandemic hit and were all out of the office for a while.

So I'm trying to understand the results and see if I suck or not.  When I work with others they don't seem to think so, but I just thought I'd check here and ask if this is how this always goes...

Everyone I talked to about these progress reviews state that nobody ever gets a high grade on them.

I had a teacher in college that told me he never gave anybody higher than a C; and I was like, why would I bother taking your class if no matter how hard I tried it would guaranteed affect my grade point average that way?  So I switched to Technical Writing instead; and class served me well.

Comment: Depends what these reviews are for you've forgot to include that. If they are used in any way for pay rises / bonuses then that's why you've been given a low score.

Comment: This teacher who gave Cs - was he a good teacher? Did he teach an interesting subject that would be valuable for you to learn? If you don't know the answer to that, what does that tell you about yourself?

Comment: That person should not be a teacher. An 'A' should always be achievable.

Comment: Heh... at my university, 69% would have been just short of a first class degree - but we also weren't graded on curves.

Comment: Did you really only get a number from the review? Was there no commentary or guidance for improvement? You've been there 3 years - what did you get for your other reviews?

Comment: I got the answer I needed, but I also got the down votes I usually get when I ask a question on this site.  Big surprise. Not.  ****sigh****

Comment: @leeand00 - part of that is this is such a subjective question, and really, only your own company can tell you if those are good marks or not.  At my company, the numbers also correspond to a level, so on a 4 level field, 1=needs improvement, 2=performing as expected, 3=doing well above average, 4=a leader in the field.  If your company doesn't tell you what the numbers mean, none of us would be able to do so either.  Downvotes mean the question is unanswerable, really.

Comment: @leeand00, What did you get on your performance evaluation in the first 2 years ? Did you have a different manager who graded you differently ? - In general, do most coworkers get the similar evaluations as you do because the company wants to save money and does not want to give big salary raises to most employees ?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 Yes, I had a different manager, and there were no numbers on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that there is no way to know how to interpret the scores you are given as part of your review. You should talk to your manager about what they mean. But I will say some general things about company reviews.

Company reviews are a whole different ballgame from student grades. You say it yourself. In school 69% is a D, and D is a poor result. Students are used to getting 80% or 90% and being disappointed if they don't. Everybody expects to get a "good" score and an "average" one is seen as disappointing by almost everyone. (I'll leave the mathematicians to point out the contradiction in that.) You can also look up "grade inflation" to see how teachers have responded to this - essentially raising the marks they give out to make their students happier, and improve their student feedback scores. Even students in the bottom half of the class are given "above average" scores. Grade inflation happens at the institution level too.

Companies don't have to worry about this. They only want to compare employees with each other. They have some average employees, some who are better than average and some who are worse. But they are better or worse compared with other employees, and some of those employees have been working much longer than you. If the company is one that really only hires extremely smart people you can be super-smart, graduate from your course at the top of your class, and still wind up getting an "average" in your first company review. I worked as a team lead in a company very like that, and I always had to start by explaining to people who had never had less than a "very good" appraisal in their lives that an "average" rating meant you were doing really well and had a great future in the company.

So go talk to your manager, ask him what this means for you. But don't go in assuming that you've been "marked down" for some reason. Or even that "69%" is below the average for your position. There's a very good chance it is above average.

Comment: ****Phew**** Okay thanks!  I was upset because I don't want to loose my job.  I also see that I've gotten my usual marks for asking a question the workplace.  Some out there doesn't like the questions that I ask.

Comment: I never really got a review at any other job I worked.  And I took a class in school called Organizational Communication; you would have thought they'd have covered this; but they didn't.

Comment: I'm not telling you this is a good review. Go to your manager and get them to explain it.

Answer (score 2):

The people to ask are the people at your company as different companies have varied standards. Additionally, these ratings can be quite biased in a number of ways. For example, since they’re often used to determine eligibility for pay raises and bonuses, a company that’s performing poorly overall, might be inclined to give lower ratings since they can’t afford to pay out as much.

IMO, it’s better to focus on the qualitative feedback you receive—-not just on the performance review but throughout the year. Think of it not as criticism but as opportunities for improvement. If you feel that the feedback is consistently unfair or your metrics don’t improve even after following your superiors’ recommendations, it may be time to start looking for your next job.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes more sense; thank you!  I'm more concerned about job security and continuity of income than pay.

Comment: There are some angles there I didn't think of.'